# The record package in Flutter Web returns an infinite time value

Tags: flutter, dart

I use the following code to get the bytes

dart

```
record.start(path: recordFilePath)
record.stop().then((value) async {
                   final result = await http.get(Uri.parse(value!));
                   Uint8List data = result.bodyBytes.buffer.asUint8List();
                   //convert bytes to blob
                   double duration = getWebDuration(data);
                 });
```

And then with the following code, I try to get the recorded time, it returns an infinite value

dart

```
Future<double> getWebDuration(Uint8List bytes) async {
   final blob = Blob([bytes]);
   final url = Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
   final audio = AudioElement()
     ..src = url
     ..autoplay = false;
   document.body?.append(audio);
   final duration = await Future(() {
     final completer = Completer<double>();
     audio.onLoadedData.listen((event) {
       final duration = audio.duration;
       Url. revokeObjectUrl(url);
       audio.remove();
       completer.complete(duration.toDouble());
     });
     return completer. future;
   });
   return duration;
}
```

I even use ffmpeg on the server side to get the duration of the recording, but it also returns NaN

nodejs

```
async function getDuration(filePath) {
     const cmd = `ffmpeg -i "${filePath}" 2>&1 | grep "Duration" | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//`;
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
             if (error) {
                 reject(error);
             }
             resolve(convertDurationToMilliseconds(stdout.trim()));
         });
     });
}
```

Both of these functions work for other media but not for recorded value

Of course, this is not a problem in Android and I only have this problem in the web